# Rename row field when generating json file with php

Tags: php, json

i'm generating a json file using php and a odbc connection. My query is translated well to the json file.

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT  Date1, Nett FROM database WHERE Date1 BETWEEN '$bdate' AND '$edate' AND String13='$sr' ORDER BY Date1 desc;
```

This will be in json:

```
{"Date1":"2015-10-09 00:00:00.000","Nett":"20860.0"}
```

But i want that the output is

```
{"date":"2015-10-09","value":20860}
```

So basically i want that the rows "Date1" and "Nett" 
automatically be translated to "date" and "value" in the json file.
optional also just the date and not datetime.

I want to rename this field because my chart is feeded by json file that needs the field date and value.

This is what i have so far..

```
//json
$json_file_name = "uniwin/json/File_export.json";
$json_file_name = str_replace(" ", "_", $json_file_name);

// Open output file
$fp = fopen($json_file_name, 'w');

// Write JSON list start    
fwrite($fp, '[');

// Write each object as a row
$isFirstRow = true;
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($json)) {

    if (!$isFirstRow) {
        fwrite($fp, ',');
    } else {
        $isFirstRow = false;
    }

    fwrite($fp, json_encode($row));
}

// Write JSON list end
fwrite($fp, ']');

// Close file and MySQL connection
fclose($fp);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(Date1, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
  CAST(Nett AS INT) AS value
FROM database 
WHERE Date1 BETWEEN '$bdate' AND '$edate' AND String13='$sr' 
ORDER BY Date1 desc;
```

`AS date` you can use any alias

`'%Y-%m-%d'` and select any format

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Could have just used `DATE(Date1)` as format change was not required

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. i get DATE_FORMAT is not a recognized built-in function name.Can you provide me some other solution?

Comment: BTW: When i changd the query to (SELECT Date1 AS date ...) it's renamed my json file excelent! So that is working fine!

Comment: I think you use MySQL, for MS SQL you can see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: Thanks for the advice!